# How to evaluate double integrals of a surface over a specific region?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I found this exercise while exercising for the exam:

Let $T$ $\subset$ $R^2$ be the triangle with these vertices  $(0,0), (2,0), (0,1)$ and let $\Omega$ be the surface defined like this:

$\Omega$ = {$(x,y,z) \in R^3 : z^2 - x^2 - y^2 = 0, z > 0, (x,y) \in T$}

Evaluate $\iint_{\Omega}x^2 y dS $

I'm having a hard time solving it because it confounds me... I can't seem to "visualize" the situation. What's exactly the role of the triangular region, where am I going to have to use that region when solving the integral?

Could you help me visualize the problem in some way?

Comment: It matters if the triangle is taken to be hollow nor nonhollow

Comment: @FShrike Let's suppose it is non hollow, how does one handle the request of the exercise?

Comment: I wish I could say. I've upvoted, but I haven't studied multivariable calculus in sufficient detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ is not too hard to picture. It's a right triangle in the first quadrant of the $x,y$ plane with vertices at the given points.

$\Omega$ is the set of points in $\Bbb R^3$ on the given cone $z^2-x^2-y^2=0$ above the plane $z=0$, and further restricted to lie above $T$. To help visualize the cone, you can use [level sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set): take a slice of the cone at some plane $z=z_0$, then determine what kind of curve is left behind in the equation $z_0^2 - x^2 - y^2 = 0$. For example, at $z_0=\pm1$ we have $x^2+y^2=1$, the unit circle; at $z_0=\pm2$, $x^2+y^2=4$, a circle of radius $2$; and so on. In any plane $z=z_0$, we end up with a circle of radius $z_0$ centered on the $z$ axis. Joining them all together forms the surface shown in the figure below. The concentric circles you see along the walls of the cone are level curves.

[image]

The additional restriction of lying above $T$ means $\Omega$ should look like the figure below on the left, a cutaway of the cone in the shape of $T$ if you were to look directly down upon it. **This is one of the roles of $T$**: it tells us how to parameterize this cutaway. The figure on the right shows a bird's-eye view.

[image] [image]

As for the integral, we can stay in Cartesian coordinates and use $z(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ in our parameterization of the integration domain,

$$\Omega = \left\{\left(x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right) \mid (x,y) \in T\right\}$$

This gives us two candidates for evaluating the surface integral,

$$\iint_\Omega x^2 y \, dS = \iint_T x^2 y \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2+1} \, dx\,dy = \begin{cases} \displaystyle \sqrt2 \int_0^2 \int_0^{1-\tfrac x2} x^2 y \, dy \, dx \\ \displaystyle \sqrt2 \int_0^1 \int_0^{2-2y} x^2 y \, dx \, dy \end{cases} = \boxed{\frac{2\sqrt2}{15}}$$

---

Just for the fun of considering a slightly more involved approach, we can convert to cylindrical coordinates. If $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, then $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r$. The line forming the hypotenuse of $T$ transforms to

$$x+2y=2 \implies r(\cos\theta + 2\sin\theta) = 2 \implies r = \frac{2}{\sqrt5}\csc\left(\theta+\cot^{-1}2\right)$$

so that we can parameterize $\Omega$ by

$$\vec s(r,\theta) = \left\langle r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta, r\right\rangle \\
\Omega = \left\{\vec s(r,\theta) \mid 0\le r\le\frac2{\sqrt5}\csc\left(\theta+\cot^{-1}2\right) \land 0\le\theta\le\frac\pi2\right\}$$

The normal vector to $\Omega$ and the subsequent area element would be

$$\vec n = \frac{\partial \vec s}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial \vec s}{\partial \theta} = \left\langle-r\cos\theta,-r\sin\theta,r\right\rangle \implies dS = \left\|\vec n\right\| dr\,d\theta = \sqrt2\,r\,dr\,d\theta$$

The subsequent integral agrees with our previous result,

$$\iint_\Omega x^2y \, dS = \sqrt2 \int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} \int_0^{\tfrac2{\sqrt5}\csc\left(\theta+\cot^{-1}2\right)} r^4 \cos^2\theta \sin\theta \, dr \, d\theta = \boxed{\frac{2\sqrt2}{15}}$$